# Is there anyway to iterate over every type and its type parameters in TypeScript (type level programming)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-level-computation

### Question

I'd like to replace all occurrences of type `Find` with with `Replace`.

For example:

```js
type ReplaceType<Find, Replace, Type> = /* some implementation */;

type Example = {
  a: number;
  b?: "placeholder";
  c: Map<"placeholder", number> | null;
  d: {
    e: SomeCustomClass<number, "placeholder", string>;
  }[] | null;
}

type Result = ReplaceType<"placeholder", "value", Example>;
/*
type Result = {
  a: number;
  b?: "value";
  c: Map<"value", number> | null;
  d: {
    e: SomeCustomClass<number, "value", string>;
  }[] | null;
}
*/
```

Is there a way for me to do that without knowing all possible type constructors (e.g. array, `Map`, `SomeCustomClass`) before hand?

### What I've tried

I've tried researching but I couldn't find a single instance of anyone requesting this anywhere. Tbh it's difficult to google so I could have missed it.

I know you can do things like:

```js
type ReplaceType<Find, Replace, Type> = 
  Type extends Array<infer Element> ? Array<ReplaceType<Find, Replace, Element>> :
  Type extends Map<infer Key, infer Value> ? Map<Replace<Find, Replace, Key>, Replace<Find, Replace, Value>> :
  // ...
```

but you need to know all possible type constructors beforehand.
I'm wondering if there's a way to do that generically.

Comment: Use a regex in a text editor? Or the Refactor Rename tool in your TypeScript IDE?

Comment: Yes, you would likely have to know the `Map` and `SomeCustomClass` beforehand. There are ways to go through types recursivly and replace property types. The problem are likely the function signatures. A `Map` will have `.set` which takes `T` as parameter and i don't think there is an ergonomic way to iterate through those parameters too. Unions may also be a problem. I won't rule out the possibility that someone might write a type like that, but there will probably always be some edge cases where this would fail.

Comment: Just a list of edge cases to consider here: function signatures, construct signatures, things like `Record<"placeholder", any>` where the key is to be replaced, unions, array types and tuple types (I probably still missed some more cases)

Comment: @TobiasS. Yeah, deep down I know it's probably not possible. Just wanted to make sure. I'll go another route. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Because TS does not support higher kinded types, you are unable to infer generic from `SomeCustomClass`

Comment: @TobiasS.  `Map` is really easy - `T extends Map<infer K, infer V> ? Map<FindAndReplace<K, ...>, FindAndReplace<V, ...>>`. The methods don't have any part in this since they will be correctly typed if you get the generics right.

Comment: In most cases a generic class will actually use the generic parameter as a type for one of its fields, so I think you could just treat it as a normal object.

Comment: @caTS - yes, be he asked about *not* explictly knowing about types like `Map`

Answer (score 0):

So it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you also want to replace the returntypes and arguments of functions?

```
//e.g.
type ReplaceType<Find, Replace, Type> = /* some implementation */;
type Fn =(s:string) => number
type ReplacedFn = ReplaceType<Fn,number,string> // (s:string) => string
```

Do you only want to replace exact matches?

```
//e.g.
type ReplaceType<Find, Replace, Type> = /* some implementation */;
type Union = string | number
type ReplaceWithoutExactMatch = ReplaceType<Union, number, string> // string
//or this?
type ReplaceExactMatch = ReplaceType<Union, string, string> // string | number
```

So here is some code for exact matches and also replacing all arguments and return types.

```
type ExactMatch<A, B> = [A] extends [B] ? [B] extends [A] ? true : false : false

type RecursiveReplace<T, TFind, TReplace> =
  [ExactMatch<T, TFind>] extends [true] ? TReplace
  : T extends (...args: infer Args) => infer Return ?
  (...args: RecursiveReplace<Args, TFind, TReplace> extends any[] ? RecursiveReplace<Args, TFind, TReplace> : []) => RecursiveReplace<Return, TFind, TReplace>
  : { [K in keyof T]: RecursiveReplace<T[K], TFind, TReplace> }


declare const test1: { a: string, c: number[], d: { nested: string, }, tuple: [number, string, boolean], union: string | boolean | number, map: Map<string, number> }

type TestA = RecursiveReplace<typeof test1, string, number> // {a: number;c: number[];d: { nested: number; }; tuple: [number, number, boolean];union: string | boolean | number; map: {...}}
type TestB = RecursiveReplace<typeof test1, string, { key: number }>
type TestC = RecursiveReplace<typeof test1, { key: number }, boolean>
type TestD = RecursiveReplace<typeof test1, number, boolean>
type TestE = RecursiveReplace<typeof test1, string | boolean | number, boolean>

const x: TestD = null as any
x.map.set("foo", true) // valid
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&target=99&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&allowUmdGlobalAccess=true&pretty=true&ts=4.4.3&ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#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-3kM0Wq1cZj1u0OrhO-nGn3Tr0jd19+BBkNVqoVUnkkDZxPMigpz7nDPbQjZ3OcfMqwsmiEIyAisetUlUYwJ9xFQAYSvNMbxxB9USfcB2XId9ES-FsBynT1Zz-U8THPcAABFQNmcCfizExH0VWCJ3HDc0P-BBAOZRA8Kxb5M3vYioNIgtV1qddUO9bdvxQmcDnQ0AGSZFlkEKRVcPoUUtC0bkBAOSBQGQCo9wqXRwDKAAidRzW0zUlFgboK3gOxtBsHhQCAA)

Comment: This won't work with any random class (e.g. `SomeCustomClass` in my original example), correct?